# Internet Explorer Backbone events not working as expected

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view where I'm binding some events to the view's elements.
In Chrome all works as expected, but in IE11, only one event is being captured and when closely examined it doesn't have the same behaviour:

**The Events**
    events: {
            'click .colour'    : 'changeColour',
            'click .size'      : 'changeSize',
            'click .stop'       : 'stopEvent',
            'click button.draw-menu'    : 'draw',
            'click'             :'preventDefault'
    }

The view is a button that, when clicked, shows a context menu with some options (radio buttons). According to the radio button clicked (which is inside a specific div with a different class), a function is called. The problem is that when I click inside the class **colour** or class **size** element, none of the defined events is called but instead the **click** event defined above.
I have examined the **event.currentTarget** and **event.target** of the fired event and not only they are equal but refer the view's root instead the of the clicked element.
In chrome the correct event is fired and both event.currentTarget and event.target refer the correct element's and not the view's root.